# Using "Project (Data management)" in ModelBuilder using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, modelbuilder, error-999999

I have tried to change the coordinate system of a shapefile with point data with Project in ArcMap 10.8's ModelBuilder but nothing seems to work. I keep getting Error 99999.

I have tried the following;

Solution 1: Shape -> project

Solution 2: Shape -> feature to feature -> project

Alternative solution: CSV -> Make XY event layer -> Feature class to feature class -> project

When I try to do it manually on the same files it works just fine

Comment: What does your model look like?  What parameter values have you set on the Project tool?  What coordinate system does the shapefile have and what coordinate system are you trying to project into?

Comment: At this point the model only consists of the shape file and project.In project I have just seleced the shape file, where to save it and that I wish to convert from ETRS_1989 to WGS_1984. This works completely fine when I do the same procedure outside of model builder

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.